# Localhost:8080, showing 404 Error in Spring Boot Application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, tomcat, microservices

I am having some issues in regards to my spring boot microservice, I have been able to successfully connect my microservice to my SQL instance running on Google Cloud, but for some reason when I try to test if the controllers are working using a sample endpoint which simply returns a String "Working" I get a 404 not found error, I have also tried **a sample blank project**, with no dependency except the ones needed to get Spring Boot up and running, however I still face the same problem, **that is I get a 404 Not Found error, even though it is properly compiling and running. I have checked my firewall and it has not blocked the service.**

Here is the Controller

**VideoController.java**

```
package com.example.demo.Controllers;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class VideoController {


    @RequestMapping(path = "/test")
    public String index() {
        return "Greetings from Spring Boot!";
    }
}
```

**Run Logs**

```
    2021-07-11 16:53:28.677  INFO 16456 --- [           main] com.example.demo.Run.DemoApplication     : Starting DemoApplication using Java 15.0.2 on DESKTOP-OO1339O with PID 16456 (C:\Users\Engineering\IdeaProjects\gcp-demo\build\classes\java\main started by Engineering in C:\Users\Engineering\IdeaProjects\gcp-demo)
2021-07-11 16:53:28.679  INFO 16456 --- [           main] com.example.demo.Run.DemoApplication     : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2021-07-11 16:53:29.149  INFO 16456 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2021-07-11 16:53:29.161  INFO 16456 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 5 ms. Found 0 JPA repository interfaces.
2021-07-11 16:53:29.510  INFO 16456 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2021-07-11 16:53:29.517  INFO 16456 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2021-07-11 16:53:29.517  INFO 16456 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.48]
2021-07-11 16:53:29.624  INFO 16456 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2021-07-11 16:53:29.625  INFO 16456 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 913 ms
2021-07-11 16:53:29.751  INFO 16456 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2021-07-11 16:53:29.788  INFO 16456 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.4.32.Final
2021-07-11 16:53:29.888  INFO 16456 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.2.Final}
2021-07-11 16:53:29.971  INFO 16456 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2021-07-11 16:53:30.025  INFO 16456 --- [           main] c.g.cloud.sql.core.CoreSocketFactory     : Connecting to Cloud SQL instance [XXXXXXXXHIDDENFROMSTACKOVERFLOWPOST] via SSL socket.
2021-07-11 16:53:30.025  INFO 16456 --- [           main] c.g.cloud.sql.core.CoreSocketFactory     : First Cloud SQL connection, generating RSA key pair.
2021-07-11 16:53:31.820  INFO 16456 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2021-07-11 16:53:31.835  INFO 16456 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL57Dialect
2021-07-11 16:53:31.924  INFO 16456 --- [onnection adder] c.g.cloud.sql.core.CoreSocketFactory     : Connecting to Cloud SQL instance [XXXXXXXXHIDDENFROMSTACKOVERFLOWPOST] via SSL socket.
2021-07-11 16:53:32.035  INFO 16456 --- [onnection adder] c.g.cloud.sql.core.CoreSocketFactory     : Connecting to Cloud SQL instance [XXXXXXXXHIDDENFROMSTACKOVERFLOWPOST] via SSL socket.
2021-07-11 16:53:32.040  INFO 16456 --- [           main] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
2021-07-11 16:53:32.049  INFO 16456 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2021-07-11 16:53:32.099  WARN 16456 --- [           main] JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
2021-07-11 16:53:32.147  INFO 16456 --- [onnection adder] c.g.cloud.sql.core.CoreSocketFactory     : Connecting to Cloud SQL instance [XXXXXXXXHIDDENFROMSTACKOVERFLOWPOST] via SSL socket.
2021-07-11 16:53:32.245  INFO 16456 --- [onnection adder] c.g.cloud.sql.core.CoreSocketFactory     : Connecting to Cloud SQL instance [XXXXXXXXHIDDENFROMSTACKOVERFLOWPOST] via SSL socket.
2021-07-11 16:53:32.265  INFO 16456 --- [           main] c.g.c.s.core.DefaultCredentialsProvider  : Default credentials provider for service account acn-demo-app@involuted-earth-319307.iam.gserviceaccount.com
2021-07-11 16:53:32.265  INFO 16456 --- [           main] c.g.c.s.core.DefaultCredentialsProvider  : Scopes in use by default credentials: [https://www.googleapis.com/auth/pubsub, https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spanner.admin, https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spanner.data, https://www.googleapis.com/auth/datastore, https://www.googleapis.com/auth/sqlservice.admin, https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_only, https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_write, https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloudruntimeconfig, https://www.googleapis.com/auth/trace.append, https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform, https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-vision, https://www.googleapis.com/auth/bigquery, https://www.googleapis.com/auth/monitoring.write]
2021-07-11 16:53:32.277  INFO 16456 --- [           main] c.g.c.s.a.c.GcpContextAutoConfiguration  : The default project ID is XXXXXXXXHIDDENFROMSTACKOVERFLOWPOST
2021-07-11 16:53:32.353  INFO 16456 --- [onnection adder] c.g.cloud.sql.core.CoreSocketFactory     : Connecting to Cloud SQL instance [XXXXXXXXHIDDENFROMSTACKOVERFLOWPOST] via SSL socket.
2021-07-11 16:53:32.378  INFO 16456 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2021-07-11 16:53:32.389  INFO 16456 --- [           main] com.example.demo.Run.DemoApplication     : Started DemoApplication in 4.027 seconds (JVM running for 4.567)
2021-07-11 16:53:32.449  INFO 16456 --- [onnection adder] c.g.cloud.sql.core.CoreSocketFactory     : Connecting to Cloud SQL instance [XXXXXXXXHIDDENFROMSTACKOVERFLOWPOST] via SSL socket.
2021-07-11 16:53:32.554  INFO 16456 --- [onnection adder] c.g.cloud.sql.core.CoreSocketFactory     : Connecting to Cloud SQL instance [XXXXXXXXHIDDENFROMSTACKOVERFLOWPOST] via SSL socket.
2021-07-11 16:53:32.659  INFO 16456 --- [onnection adder] c.g.cloud.sql.core.CoreSocketFactory     : Connecting to Cloud SQL instance [involuted-earth-319307:australia-southeast1:cloud-demo] via SSL socket.
2021-07-11 16:53:32.768  INFO 16456 --- [onnection adder] c.g.cloud.sql.core.CoreSocketFactory     : Connecting to Cloud SQL instance [XXXXXXXXHIDDENFROMSTACKOVERFLOWPOST] via SSL socket.
2021-07-11 16:53:38.167  INFO 16456 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2021-07-11 16:53:38.167  INFO 16456 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2021-07-11 16:53:38.168  INFO 16456 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 1 ms
```

My Application Properties File

Application.properties

```
  spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true
spring.datasource.url=SOMEVALUE HERE
spring.datasource.username=SOMEVALUE HERE
spring.datasource.password=SOMEVALUEHERE
spring.cloud.gcp.sql.database-name=SOMEVALUEHERE
spring.cloud.gcp.sql.instance-connection-name=SOMVEVALUEHERE
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

My File Structure

[image: File Structure]

My Application Run Class

**DemoApplication.Java**

```
package com.example.demo.Run;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

[image: Postman Request]

Comment: What URL are you trying to access your service at?

Comment: add @CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:8080") on method level and try again

Comment: your implementation looks okk @CrossOrigin and see

Comment: I have added @CrossOrigin(origins = "localhost:8080") to the top of the VideoController class, I still get http 404

Comment: @SelvakumarAnushan CORS does nothing have to do with this problem!

Comment: @DeepAlgo212345: `spring-dao` version `1.2.9` is part of a prehistoric Spring 1.x. If you have problems removing it, post another question (Spring Boot N.x uses Spring (N + 3).x).

Comment: please ask a new question instead of changing this question, which makes existing answers irrelevant

Answer (score 1):

`DemoApplication` is in the `com.example.demo.Run` package. This means that its component scanning, enabled via `@SpringBootApplication`, will find components in `com.example.demo.Run` and in any sub-packages such as `com.example.demo.Run.example`. The rest of your code, therefore, isn’t in a package where it’ll be found.

I would fix this by moving `DemoApplication` up into the `com.example.demo` package. This will mean that components in any of your existing `com.example.demo.*` packages is found.

Alternatively, you could leave `DemoApplication` where it is and use the [`scanBasePackages` attribute on `@SpringBootApplication`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/SpringBootApplication.html#scanBasePackages--) to list all your other `com.example.demo.*` packages. This will be more verbose than moving `DemoApplication` and would require changes every time you introduce a new package.

Comment: Sorry, for the delay, but I think this fixes my problem but I am not sure how I would go about implementing it, would it be something like this

@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = {"com.example.demo"})

This is inside my DemoApplication.Java file which is inside the Package Run

Comment: Yes, that should work. I’d still favour moving `DemoApplication` as it’s the [recommended](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.4.x/reference/htmlsingle/#using-boot-locating-the-main-class) way to structure your code.

Comment: Hmm, I have reedited my question, I have tried moving DemoApplication to the main package so inside (com.example.demo) but I get another error

Comment: Please don’t edit your question in a way that completely changes it as it makes the existing comments and answers seem useless. Ask a new question for the new problem instead.

Comment: Hi, I can no longer create new questions due to my account limit (1 question per day) this is why I did not create a new one.

Comment: It would be better to wait. Editing to completely change what a question is asking isn’t in the spirit of Stack Overflow and wastes the time of those trying to help you.

Answer (score 0):

As you said your first problem was because of the package level of your main class and Controller class. But the second problem does not seem to depend on refactoring the main class. It's related to conflict of the version of your JDK or another library